# Unable to correctly enable CSP and Policy with Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

```
render: {
    csp: {
      hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
      reportOnly: false,
      policies: {
        'form-action': [
            "'self'",
            PRIMARY_HOSTS
        ],
        'default-src': [
            "'sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='",
            "'self'", 
            "'unsafe-inline'", 
            PRIMARY_HOSTS
        ],
        'style-src': [
            "'sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='",
            "'self'", 
            "'unsafe-inline'", 
            PRIMARY_HOSTS
        ],
        'worker-src': [
            "'sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='",
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            PRIMARY_HOSTS,
        ],
        'script-src': [
            "'sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='",
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            PRIMARY_HOSTS,
        ],
        'script-src-elem': [
            "'sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='",
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            PRIMARY_HOSTS,
        ],
        'connect-src': [PRIMARY_HOSTS],
        'base-uri': [PRIMARY_HOSTS],
        'report-uri': [PRIMARY_HOSTS],
  },
  addMeta: true
}
```

This above is my current CSP setup in Nuxt 3, I'm unable to get the policy to work as I receive the below error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-8vcDc+Pxpd4ghm3kZ0uncZkL0MEwekDRS8XVBN/nq7k='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Individually each script returns:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://crm.domain.io/_nuxt/debf4b6.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src ". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I've tried following the Nuxt CSP guide, as well as Google's.

I'm unsure what I am doing wrong, I have set target to server, and PRIMARY_HOST is set:

```
crm.domain.com
```

For reference, crm.domain.com is pointing to a Vercel CNAME.

Comment: Did you get this working in the end?